# How to make an mplfinance candle stick chart showing cursors and dates

Tags: charts, interactive, mplfinance

Does anyone know how can I display the cursor and show the dates and prices on the mplfinance charts in the juypter notebook.

It only shows a static chart, not an interactive chart for me.

Appreciated.

Steven.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7EC1.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are actually asking two questions here.

1. How to get interactivity inside jupyter notebook.
2. How to display a cursor and x,y values (date,price) on an mplfinance chart.

---

**1. How to get interactivity inside jupyter notebook.**

The first question is easy. To get basic matplotlib interactivity inside jupyter notebook, you need to install and activate **ipympl**:

```sh
pip install ipympl
jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink --sys-prefix --overwrite ipympl
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipympl
```

After the above, start your jupyter notebook, and run the following in the first cell:

```py
%matplotlib widget
```

Then, when you call `mpf.plot(df,...)` you will get the standard matplotlib widget based gui that you see when you run an mplfinance script from the command line (i.e. from outside of jupyter notebook or any ide).

[**Read more about ipympl here**](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl#ipympl).

---

**2. How to display a cursor and x,y values (date,price) on an mplfinance chart.**

Mplfinance presently does not *directly* support interactivity (hopefully sometime later this year).

However mplfinance has the ability to return the Figure and Axes objects that it creates (by setting kwarg `returnfig=True`).  ([Click here for more information about accessing mplfinance's Figure and Axes objects](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects))

Once you have the Figure and Axes objects, you can use standard matplotlib interactivity widgets to do pretty much whatever you want.  [**See here for an example of placing a cursor on an mplfinance plot**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/scratch_pad/multicursor_macd.py).

Consult [the matplotlib widget documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html) and [interactivity documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/interactive.html) for more information.

---

Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of the [**mplfinance package**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#mplfinance).